# How to delete items from a paginated list in Apollo?

Tags: pagination, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I'm wondering how to delete items in a paginated list so that I always show the same number of items. My current approach isn’t working (the list gets smaller after each delete):

```
const GET_PAGINATED_POSTS = gql`
  query postsBySize($page: Int!, $pageSize: Int!) {
    postsPage(page: $page, size: $pageSize) {
      _id
      title
    }
  }
`;

deletePost() {
  this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: DELETE_POST,
    variables: {
      postId: this.post._id,
      commentIds: this.post.comments.map(x => x._id)
    },
    update: (cache, { data: { deletePost } }) => {
      const query = {
        query: GET_PAGINATED_POSTS,
        variables: {
          page: 0,
          pageSize: 10
        },
      };

      const data = cache.readQuery({ ...query });
      data.postsPage = data.postsPage.filter(post => post._id != this.post._id)
      cache.writeQuery({ ...query, data })
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your response is paginated, the client has no idea what the next post should be -- it fetched 10 posts with the initial query and so that's what's in your store.

Instead of manually updating the cache by utilizing `update`, you should instead use `refetchQueries`:

```
deletePost() {
  this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: DELETE_POST,
    variables: {
      postId: this.post._id,
      commentIds: this.post.comments.map(x => x._id)
    },
    refetchQueries: [
      {
        query: GET_PAGINATED_POSTS,
        variables: {
          page: 0,
          pageSize: 10,
        },
      },
    ],
  })
}
```

This will force Apollo to fetch new results for your `GET_PAGINATED_POSTS`, updating the store and your UI accordingly.

Comment: This might be the only working way of doing this, but that seems extremely under-optimal to me... If only because things like `optimisticResponse` can then not be used, and the server has to be hit needlessly, and everything is slow... There should definitely be a way to update the cache directly and remove the deleted object.

Comment: can we have an example with `cursors` for pagination. For example if we are using gmail like application and we are on page 3. if we delete any item from the list we need to refetch data for that particular list.

Comment: in cursor based pagination we send cursor, before/after and last/first param.
in gmail like application. we are on 3rd page and we delete any email.
We need to refetch the data for 3rd page. So we need to send cursor, after and first.
when we are on 3rd page we only have cursors for 3rd page. So if we send cursor of top item. it will be exclued from backend. Because query suppose to return data after cursor. another case is if we are on a last page having only one record. if we delete that record page should switch to second last page with new count and page numbers.